# Linux Ubuntu Serial Com Port for Android Device

Tags: android, linux, serial-port, usbserial

I am connecting my Android Phone with my Linux Ubuntu Laptop over Micro USB(Android) to USB(Laptop) cable for Development/Debugging using Android Studio.
Will it possible to open the USB Port as Serial Communication port for sending and receiving data to/from Phone and Linux?
I wan to implement Java based test application on Linux which will talk with Android App over Serial.

I was trying to list the device when phone is connected using `$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*` but I did not find it listed under `/dev`.

How can I use USB as serial on Linux for Serial communication with Android Device?
Do I need to have USB serial converter cable something like:

`(Android) Micro USB<--->Serial Male = Serial Female<-->USB (Linux)`

Or can it be possible using Virtual Com Port, how?
Thanks for the help, highly appreciated.

Comment: The Android device could be setup as the USB slave with a gadget serial device driver.  The PC as USB host would have a **/dev/ttyACM**n device node.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the gadget serial device driver. Is it some drivers provided by Android sdk? Can you post link to example.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt or https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-trusty-3.10/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the links, do I need to rebuild the Linux kernel to set my Ubuntu as USB slave device. When I plugin my Android I don't see `/dev/ttyACMn` or even `/dev/ttyUSBn`. I cloud see the mobile listed under the `lsusb` command. But no tty to open and connect.